# Terminal color in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, colors, terminal

Is there a Ruby module for colorizing strings in a Linux terminal?

Comment: I won't post an answer, so I don't revive this, but there's a nifty gem called "colored." it's as simple as: `"string".red` to get red text. [More info](http://rubydoc.info/gems/colored/1.2/frames) :D

Comment: You can check this as well as there are options to do that without installing another Gem: [Colorized Ruby output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489183/colorized-ruby-output)

Answer (score 17):

I prefer the [Rainbow gem](https://github.com/sickill/rainbow) since it also supports Windows if the win32console gem has been installed.

You can use it like this:

```
puts "some " + "red".color(:red) + " and " + "blue on yellow".color(:blue).background(:yellow)
```

Comment: This is a great gem. Well maintained and simple.

Answer (score 10):

Ehm, OK, Google was my friend :)

http://term-ansicolor.rubyforge.org/

Comment: The link is broken (times out).

Answer (score 10):

All you have to do is start with `"\e[##m"` and end with `"\e[0m"`

Just replace the ## with the color number. Examples are:

- `31:Red`
- `32:Green`
- `33:Yellow`
- `34:Blue`
- `35:Magenta`
- `36:Teal`
- `37:Grey`

`1:Bold (can be used with any color)`

Here is a Ruby script to show all the terminal colors. [Download it](https://github.com/mvndaai/ruby-toolbox/blob/master/terminal_colors.rb) or run the code below.

```
def color(index)
  normal = "\e[#{index}m#{index}\e[0m"
  bold = "\e[#{index}m\e[1m#{index}\e[0m"
  "#{normal}  #{bold}  "
end

8.times do|index|
  line = color(index + 1)
  line += color(index + 30)
  line += color(index + 90)
  line += color(index + 40)
  line += color(index + 100)
  puts line
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Using String class methods like:

```
class String
def black;          "\033[30m#{self}\033[0m" end
def red;            "\033[31m#{self}\033[0m" end
def green;          "\033[32m#{self}\033[0m" end
def brown;          "\033[33m#{self}\033[0m" end
def blue;           "\033[34m#{self}\033[0m" end
def magenta;        "\033[35m#{self}\033[0m" end
def cyan;           "\033[36m#{self}\033[0m" end
def gray;           "\033[37m#{self}\033[0m" end
end
```

and usage:

```
puts "This prints green".green
puts "This prints red".red
```

Comment: Precise and concise, the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of the Ruby colorize gem, which I recently downloaded. Once you download and include it into your program, you can add

```
.colorize(:blue)
```

to the end of any string. You can use most colors, including preceding the color by light_ like so:

```
.colorize(:light_blue)
```

you can also do background colors,
EG:

```
puts "mytext".colorize(:background => :green
```

colorized underlines,
EG:

```
puts "mytext".on_blue.underline
```

Or use HTML-like tags for it as well

```
puts <blue> "text text text" </blue>
```

For the colorize GitHub, go to [The colorize GitHub](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize).

You can install the colorize gem by typing

```
gem install colorize
```

into your terminal, command prompt, whatever. Then put this into your file *before you put in the uses of it*.

For example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'colorize'
puts "mytext".colorize(:red)
```

But *not*:

```
puts "mytext".colorize(:red)
require 'rubygems'
require 'colorize'
```

The require statements *must* be in the program in lines *before* you use the gem.