# How can I use Ruby to colorize the text output to a terminal?

Tags: ruby, colors, console-application

Using Ruby, how can I perform background and foreground text colorization for output in the terminal?

I remember, when programming Pascal we all used to write our own `textcolor(…)` procedures to make our small educational programs look more pretty and presentational.

How would I go about coding an equivalent of that in Ruby?  Is there any built-in support in the core library that lends itself to this?  If not, what would be an idiomatic way to add it?

Comment: So it's imposible to get "orange" color for exemple?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/kigster/colored2

Answer (score 422, accepted):

UPDATE: Colorize is copyleft.

So i would try the rainbow gem:

https://github.com/ku1ik/rainbow

Installation:

```
gem install rainbow
```

Usage:

```
require 'rainbow/refinement'
using Rainbow

puts "I am now red".red
puts "I am now blue".blue
puts "Testing".yellow
```

Comment: Much easier than doing it by hand!

Comment: Well, nice solution. But it made me 5 gems to install instead of one, to run it

Comment: Could someone tell me if Colorize does work in Cygwin Terminal ? I tried running the above code in Cygwin but it comes out without colors..

Comment: This will work fine in a Windows Command Prompt if you install the `win32console` gem and `require 'win32console'` after `colorize`.

Comment: @Ben I haven't personally tried it, but since Ruby 2.0 you should no longer need the `win32console` gem. https://github.com/luislavena/win32console/issues/17#issuecomment-20811539

Comment: Any way to make this work with Sumblime Text console?

Comment: This gem is licensed under GPL so (I think) it can't be used in proprietary software. http://jonathannen.com/2013/07/07/license-your-gems.html

Comment: Appending to @AndreiBotalov's comment: **this gem should be avoided. It uses a strong copyleft license (GPL2.0)**, so if you use it in your project, you are required to not only open source your code, but you must also license your project under GPL. 

The more popular alternative nowadays is the [Rainbow gem](https://github.com/sickill/rainbow)

Answer (score 293):

Combining the answers above, you can implement something that works like the gem colorize without needing another dependency.

```
class String
  # colorization
  def colorize(color_code)
    "\e[#{color_code}m#{self}\e[0m"
  end

  def red
    colorize(31)
  end

  def green
    colorize(32)
  end

  def yellow
    colorize(33)
  end

  def blue
    colorize(34)
  end

  def pink
    colorize(35)
  end

  def light_blue
    colorize(36)
  end
end
```

Comment: ah, nice edit Nick. Yes of course there's no need to pass self around. I was tired when I wrote this :)

Comment: will this work in windows too?

Comment: It works in windows if you are using [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)

Comment: I like this better than colorize as this only changes the foreground color.  colorize seems to always change the background color.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but wouldn't it be better to use a closure here?

Answer (score 284):

As String class methods (Unix only):

```rb
class String
def black;          "\e[30m#{self}\e[0m" end
def red;            "\e[31m#{self}\e[0m" end
def green;          "\e[32m#{self}\e[0m" end
def brown;          "\e[33m#{self}\e[0m" end
def blue;           "\e[34m#{self}\e[0m" end
def magenta;        "\e[35m#{self}\e[0m" end
def cyan;           "\e[36m#{self}\e[0m" end
def gray;           "\e[37m#{self}\e[0m" end

def bg_black;       "\e[40m#{self}\e[0m" end
def bg_red;         "\e[41m#{self}\e[0m" end
def bg_green;       "\e[42m#{self}\e[0m" end
def bg_brown;       "\e[43m#{self}\e[0m" end
def bg_blue;        "\e[44m#{self}\e[0m" end
def bg_magenta;     "\e[45m#{self}\e[0m" end
def bg_cyan;        "\e[46m#{self}\e[0m" end
def bg_gray;        "\e[47m#{self}\e[0m" end

def bold;           "\e[1m#{self}\e[22m" end
def italic;         "\e[3m#{self}\e[23m" end
def underline;      "\e[4m#{self}\e[24m" end
def blink;          "\e[5m#{self}\e[25m" end
def reverse_color;  "\e[7m#{self}\e[27m" end
end
```

And usage:

```
puts "I'm back green".bg_green
puts "I'm red and back cyan".red.bg_cyan
puts "I'm bold and green and backround red".bold.green.bg_red
```

In my console:

[image]

#### Additionally,

```rb
def no_colors
  self.gsub /\e\[\d+m/, ""
end
```

removes formatting characters.

#### Note

```
puts "\e[31m" # set format (red foreground)
puts "\e[0m"   # clear format
puts "green-#{"red".red}-green".green # will be green-red-normal, because of \e[0
```

Comment: Bold off should use escape code 22 not 21: `def bold;           "\e[1m#{self}\e[22m" end`

Comment: @KanatBolazar, Some systems supports [21](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#reset). But I change it to 22 for capability. Thanks.

Comment: This is great, I put it in an initializer in my Rails application. Works like a charm!

Comment: Fantastic tips. So easy and no dependencies. Very very well done!

Comment: In Windows 10 `cmd.exe`, `puts "\e[0"` does not work to clear format; `puts "\e[0m"` must be used

Comment: @Nnnes, thanks for you comment. The `m` must be used everywhere. Fixed.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/equivalent/74b1dec423f186c6e594f00b9aacff10  mirror

Comment: Decided against monkey patching, but used the methods. Thanks!!

Answer (score 48):

I wrote a little method to test out the basic color modes, based on answers by Erik Skoglund and others.

```
#outputs color table to console, regular and bold modes
def colortable
  names = %w(black red green yellow blue pink cyan white default)
  fgcodes = (30..39).to_a - [38]

  s = ''
  reg  = "\e[%d;%dm%s\e[0m"
  bold = "\e[1;%d;%dm%s\e[0m"
  puts '                       color table with these background codes:'
  puts '          40       41       42       43       44       45       46       47       49'
  names.zip(fgcodes).each {|name,fg|
    s = "#{fg}"
    puts "%7s "%name + "#{reg}  #{bold}   "*9 % [fg,40,s,fg,40,s,  fg,41,s,fg,41,s,  fg,42,s,fg,42,s,  fg,43,s,fg,43,s,  
      fg,44,s,fg,44,s,  fg,45,s,fg,45,s,  fg,46,s,fg,46,s,  fg,47,s,fg,47,s,  fg,49,s,fg,49,s ]
  }
end
```

example output:
[image: ruby colortest]

Answer (score 40):

You can use ANSI escape sequences to do this in the console. I know this works on Linux and Mac OS X, but I'm not sure if the Windows console (cmd) supports ANSI.

I did it in Java, but the ideas are the same.

```
// Foreground color
public static final String BLACK_TEXT()   { return "\033[30m";}
public static final String RED_TEXT()     { return "\033[31m";}
public static final String GREEN_TEXT()   { return "\033[32m";}
public static final String BROWN_TEXT()   { return "\033[33m";}
public static final String BLUE_TEXT()    { return "\033[34m";}
public static final String MAGENTA_TEXT() { return "\033[35m";}
public static final String CYAN_TEXT()    { return "\033[36m";}
public static final String GRAY_TEXT()    { return "\033[37m";}

// Background color
public static final String BLACK_BACK()   { return "\033[40m";}
public static final String RED_BACK()     { return "\033[41m";}
public static final String GREEN_BACK()   { return "\033[42m";}
public static final String BROWN_BACK()   { return "\033[43m";}
public static final String BLUE_BACK()    { return "\033[44m";}
public static final String MAGENTA_BACK() { return "\033[45m";}
public static final String CYAN_BACK()    { return "\033[46m";}
public static final String WHITE_BACK()   { return "\033[47m";}

// ANSI control characters
public static final String RESET_COLORS() { return "\033[0m";}
public static final String BOLD_ON()      { return "\033[1m";}
public static final String BLINK_ON()     { return "\033[5m";}
public static final String REVERSE_ON()   { return "\033[7m";}
public static final String BOLD_OFF()     { return "\033[22m";}
public static final String BLINK_OFF()    { return "\033[25m";}
public static final String REVERSE_OFF()  { return "\033[27m";}
```

Comment: This works and has the advantage of not requiring a gem, which might annoy some people.

Comment: The Windows console does indeed support ANSI codes.

Answer (score 19):

While the other answers will do the job fine for most people, the "correct" Unix way of doing this should be mentioned. Since all types of text terminals do not support these sequences, you can query the *terminfo* database, an abstraction over the capabilites of various text terminals.  This might seem mostly of historical interest – software terminals in use today generally support the ANSI sequences – but it does have (at least) one practical effect: it is sometimes useful to be able to set the environment variable `TERM` to `dumb` to avoid all such styling, for example when saving the output to a text file.  Also, it feels good to do things *right*. :-)

You can use the [ruby-terminfo](http://www.a-k-r.org/ruby-terminfo/) gem. It needs some C compiling to install; I was able to install it under my Ubuntu 14.10 system with:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
$ gem install ruby-terminfo --user-install
```

Then you can query the database like this (see the [terminfo man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?terminfo+5) for a list of what codes are available):

```rb
require 'terminfo' 
TermInfo.control("bold")
puts "Bold text"
TermInfo.control("sgr0")
puts "Back to normal."
puts "And now some " + TermInfo.control_string("setaf", 1) + 
     "red" + TermInfo.control_string("sgr0") + " text."
```

Here's a little wrapper class I put together to make things a little more simple to use.

```rb
require 'terminfo'

class Style
  def self.style() 
    @@singleton ||= Style.new
  end

  colors = %w{black red green yellow blue magenta cyan white}
  colors.each_with_index do |color, index|
    define_method(color) { get("setaf", index) }
    define_method("bg_" + color) { get("setab", index) }
  end

  def bold()  get("bold")  end
  def under() get("smul")  end
  def dim()   get("dim")   end
  def clear() get("sgr0")  end

  def get(*args)
    begin
      TermInfo.control_string(*args)
    rescue TermInfo::TermInfoError
      ""
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```rb
c = Style.style
C = c.clear
puts "#{c.red}Warning:#{C} this is #{c.bold}way#{C} #{c.bg_red}too much #{c.cyan + c.under}styling#{C}!"
puts "#{c.dim}(Don't you think?)#{C}"
```

[image: Output of above Ruby script]

(edit) Finally, if you'd rather not require a gem, you can rely on the `tput` program, [as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10065/106807) – Ruby example:

```
puts "Hi! " + `tput setaf 1` + "This is red!" + `tput sgr0`
```

Comment: Major, *major* +1 for use of `tput`. Can't even articulate how much hair loss `tput` has saved me.

Answer (score 16):

I made this method that could help. It is not a big deal but it works:

```
def colorize(text, color = "default", bgColor = "default")
    colors = {"default" => "38","black" => "30","red" => "31","green" => "32","brown" => "33", "blue" => "34", "purple" => "35",
     "cyan" => "36", "gray" => "37", "dark gray" => "1;30", "light red" => "1;31", "light green" => "1;32", "yellow" => "1;33",
      "light blue" => "1;34", "light purple" => "1;35", "light cyan" => "1;36", "white" => "1;37"}
    bgColors = {"default" => "0", "black" => "40", "red" => "41", "green" => "42", "brown" => "43", "blue" => "44",
     "purple" => "45", "cyan" => "46", "gray" => "47", "dark gray" => "100", "light red" => "101", "light green" => "102",
     "yellow" => "103", "light blue" => "104", "light purple" => "105", "light cyan" => "106", "white" => "107"}
    color_code = colors[color]
    bgColor_code = bgColors[bgColor]
    return "\033[#{bgColor_code};#{color_code}m#{text}\033[0m"
end
```

Here's how to use it:

```
puts "#{colorize("Hello World")}"
puts "#{colorize("Hello World", "yellow")}"
puts "#{colorize("Hello World", "white","light red")}"
```

Possible improvements could be:

- `colors` and `bgColors` are being defined each time the method is called and they don't change.
- Add other options like `bold`, `underline`, `dim`, etc.

This method does not work for `p`, as `p` does an `inspect` to its argument. For example:

```
p "#{colorize("Hello World")}"
```

will show "\e[0;38mHello World\e[0m"

I tested it with `puts`, `print`, and the Logger gem, and it works fine.

---

I improved this and made a class so `colors` and `bgColors` are class constants and `colorize` is a class method:

EDIT: Better code style, defined constants instead of class variables, using symbols instead of strings, added more options like, bold, italics, etc.

```
class Colorizator
    COLOURS = { default: '38', black: '30', red: '31', green: '32', brown: '33', blue: '34', purple: '35',
                cyan: '36', gray: '37', dark_gray: '1;30', light_red: '1;31', light_green: '1;32', yellow: '1;33',
                light_blue: '1;34', light_purple: '1;35', light_cyan: '1;36', white: '1;37' }.freeze
    BG_COLOURS = { default: '0', black: '40', red: '41', green: '42', brown: '43', blue: '44',
                   purple: '45', cyan: '46', gray: '47', dark_gray: '100', light_red: '101', light_green: '102',
                   yellow: '103', light_blue: '104', light_purple: '105', light_cyan: '106', white: '107' }.freeze

    FONT_OPTIONS = { bold: '1', dim: '2', italic: '3', underline: '4', reverse: '7', hidden: '8' }.freeze

    def self.colorize(text, colour = :default, bg_colour = :default, **options)
        colour_code = COLOURS[colour]
        bg_colour_code = BG_COLOURS[bg_colour]
        font_options = options.select { |k, v| v && FONT_OPTIONS.key?(k) }.keys
        font_options = font_options.map { |e| FONT_OPTIONS[e] }.join(';').squeeze
        return "\e[#{bg_colour_code};#{font_options};#{colour_code}m#{text}\e[0m".squeeze(';')
    end
end
```

You can use it by doing:

```
Colorizator.colorize "Hello World", :gray, :white
Colorizator.colorize "Hello World", :light_blue, bold: true
Colorizator.colorize "Hello World", :light_blue, :white, bold: true, underline: true
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's what I did to make it work without needing any gems:

```
def red(mytext) ; "\e[31m#{mytext}\e[0m" ; end
puts red("hello world")
```

Then only the text in the quotes there is colored, and you're returned to your regularly scheduled program.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get, exactly: `e[32mSOMETEXT`

Comment: there was a typo in the first escape character: should be `"\e(...)"` instead of `"e\(...)"`

Answer (score 13):

I found a few:

http://github.com/ssoroka/ansi/tree/master

Examples:

```
puts ANSI.color(:red) { "hello there" }
puts ANSI.color(:green) + "Everything is green now" + ANSI.no_color
```

http://flori.github.com/term-ansicolor/

Examples:

```
print red, bold, "red bold", reset, "\n"
print red(bold("red bold")), "\n"
print red { bold { "red bold" } }, "\n"
```

http://github.com/sickill/rainbow

Example:

```
puts "this is red".foreground(:red) + " and " + "this on yellow bg".background(:yellow) + " and " + "even bright underlined!".underline.bright
```

If you are on Windows you may need to do a "gem install win32console" to enable support for colors.

Also the article [Colorizing console Ruby-script output](http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/colorizing-console-ruby-script-output/) is useful if you need to create your own gem. It explains how to add ANSI coloring to strings. You can use this knowledge to wrap it in some class that extends string or something.

Answer (score 9):

This may help you:  [Colorized ruby output](http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/colorizing-console-ruby-script-output/)

Comment: And improving the sample on this link, you can extend the String class to make it easier to use ("Hello".red): `class String; def red; colorize(self, "\033[31m"); end; end`

Answer (score 7):

I found the previous answers to be useful. However, they didn't fit the bill if I wanted to colorize something like log output *without* using any third-party libraries. The following solved the issue for me:

```rb
red = 31
green = 32
blue = 34

def color (color=blue)
  printf "\033[#{color}m";
  yield
  printf "\033[0m"
end

color { puts "this is blue" }
color(red) { logger.info "and this is red" }
```