# Show which stack frames come from my source code (not from a gem)

Tags: ruby, rake, rubymine, colorize

I'd like to be able to look at a stack trace and see at a glance which frames come from my source code. Particularly when I'm running a Rake task from the command line.

RubyMine, in its console window, highlights those stack frames which come from my source code. I love that! That's what I want.

I could use the Colorize gem or similar to do the coloring. The hard parts are

- determining which frames come from my own source code, and
- hooking into Rake or the Ruby interpreter to perform the colorization.

Advice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489183/colorized-ruby-output Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070010/how-to-output-my-ruby-commandline-text-in-different-colours

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question to be more specific.