# How do I print / puts with color?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Like in the cucumber tests, there are color-coded outputs... how do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colorized Ruby output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489183/colorized-ruby-output)

Comment: you're asking about color output to a TTY-style screen, right? The usual output for Rails is web output. To colorize that, use CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean in the context of irb?  If so, I'd suggest [Wirble](http://pablotron.org/software/wirble/) to colourize your output.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is from any gem I have, but doing thig will result in purple output.

```
puts "\e[0;35m this is a purple text \e[0m\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "\e[0;31m your text here \e[0m\n"
```