# Pry: show me the stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

Using Pry in Rails, when I hit a breakpoint in the code
    binding.pry

I want to know how I got here, who called  me, who called them, etc. But oddly I don't see that command. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the [pry-stack_explorer](https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer) plugin, it allows you to move up and down the call-stack (with `up` and `down`), display the callstack (with `show-stack`), and so on:

see here:

```
Frame number: 0/64

From: /Users/johnmair/ruby/rails_projects/personal_site/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb @ line 7 PostsController#index:

    5: def index
    6:   @posts = Post.all
 => 7:   binding.pry
    8: end

[1] pry(#<PostsController>)> show-stack

Showing all accessible frames in stack (65 in total):
--
=> #0  index <PostsController#index()>
   #1 [method]  send_action <ActionController::ImplicitRender#send_action(method, *args)>
   #2 [method]  process_action <AbstractController::Base#process_action(method_name, *args)>
   #3 [method]  process_action <ActionController::Rendering#process_action(*arg1)>
<... clipped ...>

[2] pry(#<PostsController>)> up

Frame number: 1/64
Frame type: method

From: /Users/johnmair/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb @ line 4 ActionController::ImplicitRender#send_action:

    3: def send_action(method, *args)
 => 4:   ret = super
    5:   default_render unless response_body
    6:   ret
    7: end

[3] pry(#<PostsController>)>
```

Comment: would just like to add that you can go up and down the stack with a number next to it, like: `up 9`

Answer (score 182):

To do this without any pry plugins (I was having troubles with pry-stack_explorer), just look at [`caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-caller).

I actually look for my project name to filter out all the irrelevant rails stack items. For example, if my project name were `archie` I'd use:

```
caller.select {|line| line.include? "archie" }
```

Which gives me the stack trace I'm looking for.

A shorter way would be:

```
caller.select {|x| x["archie"] }
```

Which works just as well.

Comment: This is great.  I was annoyed because it included the pry call stack and I just wanted what was specifically coming from my application.  +1!

Comment: Perfect. I added a key-combo to tmux to enter this (bind 'B' send-keys '...^M'), using a "reject" instead so it's more generic:  ```caller.reject {|x| x["vendor/bundle"] || x["/.rbenv/versions/"] }```

Comment: True to form for the Ruby community, the only useful answer is buried underneath advice to go install some plugins.

Comment: this answer deserves so many upvotes. Yes, you _can_ install more stuff on top of pry. But you could also use ruby's existing language features to get almost as far (certainly far enough to answer the OP's question!)

Comment: This answer should be the the correct one as it requires no additional plugins!

Comment: How can I make this a method I can call from the pry console? so instead of `caller.select {|line| line.include? "myapp" }` just call `my_stack` for example..

Comment: @pixelearth, look for sloneorzeszki's answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 93):

There is [pry-backtrace](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Runtime-invocation#Pry_backtrace) which show's the backtrace for the Pry session.

There is also [wtf?](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Exceptions#wtf). Which show's the backtrace of the most recent exception.  Add more question marks to view more of the backtrace or an exclamation mark to see it all.

Type [help](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Command-system#Help_command) in pry to see all the other commands :)

Comment: `pry-backtrace` is ok, but `pry-stack_explorer` plugin is way more powerful (though it's another gem, a plugin)

Comment: but the fact is sometimes you don't use all those features :)

Answer (score 3):

Extending on Paul Oliver's answer.

If you have a list of phrases you want to permanently exclude you can do that with a custom commands feature in Pry.

In `~/.pryrc`:

```
Pry::Commands.block_command "callerf", "Filter the caller backtrace" do
  output = caller.reject! { |line| line["minitest"] || line["pry"] } 
  puts "\e[31m#{output.join("\n")}\e[0m"
end
```

Calling `callerf` will result in a filtered `caller` output. Weird signs around `#{output}` is coloring to replicate the original look of the `caller`. I took the color from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489183/colorized-ruby-output).

Alternatively, if you don't want to make a custom command, use `Ctrl+R` to search through command history.

Comment: It's in home folder `~/.pryrc`. If not, just create it. `~/` always means the home folder on Unix systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use caller method which already defined inside the gem library. The return value of that method will be an array. So you can event apply array methods for search in that bunch of lines

Below is also helpful for powerful trace.
https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer