# Colored Selenium Output in Termin on Mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I'm playing with web2py and currently work through the http://killer-web-development.com/ tutorial. I'm using selenium for TDD and think colorized terminal output would be fine. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it's should work on python, but for ruby you can get some examples here: [Colorized Ruby output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489183/colorized-ruby-output)