# Ruby on Rails - How to print log messages in color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, colors, console

I'm surprised I wasn't able to find this on SO already.

I want to be able to color specific segments of strings in my log output that goes to the console.  So somethng like this:

```
"This part of the message in Green:  This part in Blue"
```

Possibly written like this:

```
Rails.logger.debug("This part of the message in Green:  ".green + "This part in Blue".blue)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is embed ANSI escape sequences for color into your debug strings, just like you would in a regular Ruby program.  There are several ways to go about this:

1. Use the [`rainbow`](https://github.com/sickill/rainbow) gem, which allows you to do this:

   `require 'rainbow'
   Rails.logger.debug(Rainbow("This message is Green").green)`

   or `require` the mixin to add methods directly to the string class:

   **Updated March 2021**:  The Rainbow Gem API has changed.  Use this now:

   `require 'rainbow/refinement'
   using Rainbow
   Rails.logger.debug("This is Green - ".green + "This is Blue".blue)`

   Previous Version (for posterity):

   `require 'rainbow/ext/string'
   Rails.logger.debug("This is Green - ".green + "This is Blue".blue)`

   **End Update**

   The Rainbow gem will automatically add the beginning and ending escape sequences to the string.
2. Use the `colorize` gem, which does the same thing as the rainbow mixin to the String class:

   `require 'colorize'
   Rails.logger.debug("This is Green - ".green + "This is Blue".blue)`
3. Put the escape sequences in yourself, using something like this:

   `Rails.logger.debug("\033[32mThis message is Green\033[0m")`
4. Write your own extension to the String class.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11482430/2062384) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363159/2062384) for an example.

For more ideas, see [How can I use Ruby to colorize the text output to a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1489183/2062384)

Comment: Use the `rainbow` gem, `colorize` uses a wildly-incompatible license.

Comment: The `rainbow` gem did not work in my case, but `colorize` works just fine. I call `Rails.logger` from a custom class in a global helper.

Comment: I recommend this link to anyone who wants to know more about how to generate colors in the outputs, without installing new gems. https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Answer (score 22):

Since [Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb), it is possible to use the internal support for coloring sql logs via `ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber`:

```
logger.debug ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.new.send(:color, "message", :red)
```

Comment: awesome worked for me, for anyone who's using this, it works with puts method also